# Not able to send regular sms instead of iMessage

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, sms

I tried everything.
Restarting iPhone, removing dialog and send again, disabling iMessage, reset network setting. Nothing helps.

Any another idea? My operator is Vodafone, and it supports SMS. It has adequate SMS balance in my pack. This recipient is available to receive SMS.

The same SIM works in other phone.

[image]
[image: not able to send message]

Comment: @ankii yes, on other phone with my sim works

Comment: @ankii yes it is

Comment: Turn on "Send as SMS" in messages settings.

Comment: @ankii yes it set, and I tried with disabled iMessage

Comment: imessages uses data to send messages... if you disconnect wifi and cellular data, it should be able to only send sms and mms (they DON'T depend on cellular data)

Comment: @GioValerio I tried, not working

Comment: Should your recipient de-register ? https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage/ Try to isolate your recipient  by testing with other people..